# remove specific characters using js regex

Tags: javascript

My question is how to make the three steps I use into one step;
how do I combine these to just one?

Thank you!

```js
var string = "1.4 Whatever";
var a = string.replace(/[0-9]/g,'');
var b = a.replace(/[\.]/g, '');
var c = b.replace(/ /g, '');

console.log(c);
```

Comment: `[0-9. ]` matches any digit or `.` or a space.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Superfast!

Comment: you just trying to remove 1.4?

Answer (score 1):

Just like this

```js
var string = "1.4 Whatever";
var a = string.replace(/[0-9\. ]/g,'');

console.log(a);
```